# MatDatepicker date undefined

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

I am having trouble passing the date which is entered in matdatepicker to a method.

The code snippet is as below:

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
   <form ng-controller="formCtrl" >
      <label style="float:left;padding:7px;"> From : </label>
      <mat-form-field style="float:left;padding:7px;">
        <input type="date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Choose a date" ng-model="fromDate">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <label style="float:left;padding:7px;"> To : </label>

      <mat-form-field style="float:left;padding:7px;">
        <input type="date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Choose a date" ng-model="toDate">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="float:left;padding:8px;" (click)="getJobsByDateRange(fromDate,toDate)">
        <b>Submit</b></button>
   </form>
</div>
```

TS :

```
getJobsByDateRange(fromDate:Date, toDate:Date){
console.log(fromDate);
}
```

Here is the output I'm getting in console:

> "undefined".

How can I print the dates in dd/MM/yyyy format?

Comment: Can you try [value]="fromDate" instead of ng-model.

Comment: this is in latest angular check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syth23?file=app%2Fdatepicker-start-view-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html

```
 <div class="div1">
       <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" >
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width mat-form-field-infix1">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" name="eventDate" [(ngModel)]="eventobj.eventDate" #eventDate="ngModel"
              required>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

          </mat-form-field>
           <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Add Event</button>
       </form>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
eventobj = {


    eventDate: "Date",

  }

   onSubmit() {
   console.log(this.eventobj.eventDate);

   }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me printing it in dd/MM/yyyy format?

Comment: Ok i will share

Comment: get Value dateobj using Ts file -                                                             dateobj = this.eventobj.eventDate;                                                              and In HTML                                                                                                  {{ dateobj | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

Answer (score 2):

```
ng-model="fromDate"
```

This doesn't exist anymore in Angular. Use this instead.

```
[(ngModel)]="fromDate"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using angular material 2 code for angular 1.

Please visit the following link to get material datepicker for angular 1.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

Comment: I am actually using angular 2.

Comment: You have used ng-controller ng-model in angular 1 syntax.

Comment: in angular 2 these things are handled differently.